# Regarding the absolute positioning property

Tags: html, css

I have a div which I have positioned using the absolute positioning property of css. And now I want to know whether there is a way to allow this div showing in the exact same position that I am seeing right now in my screen even when the screen is smaller or larger without changing the absolute positioning property of the div?

this is just a rough example:

```
<div class="name"> I am somewhere in the body </div>
...................
..................so and so codes...
..................
<div class="display">I want to stand beside the class called name </div>
```

If I write the css for the display, Then it comes exactly beside the class name

```
.display {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px; 
    top : 132px; [assume]
    left : 200px; [assume]
    border: #D3D3D3; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px #888;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px #888;
}
```

It is displaying correct for my screen. But if the screen size varies then it is no longer showing the correct position since I have used the absolute positioning property. But now I want to find whether there is a way or a trick to solve it without changing the absolute positioning property.

Comment: Don't be misguided by the "absolute" in absolute position property. It's not absolute. It's relative!

Comment: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap this like -

```
<div id="someId">
    <div class="display"></div>
</div>
```

and add this css

```
#someId {
    position: relative; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like something for the float property, change your css like:

```
.display {
    float:right;
    width: 200px; 
    border: #D3D3D3; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px #888;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px #888;
}
```